# How to forbid two conflicting options

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, argparse

Is there a way to specify to Python's ArgumentParser that two optional flags are conflicting?

```
arg_parser.add_argument('-c', '--clean', action='store_true')
arg_parser.add_argument('-d', '--dirty', action='store_true')
```

I want the user to be able to specify either none of those, or only one.

Is it achievable without further conditions?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

How about adding a [mutually exclusive group](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#mutual-exclusion):

```
group = arg_parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
group.add_argument('-c', '--clean', action='store_true')
group.add_argument('-d', '--dirty', action='store_true')
```

with this I get the following behaviour:

```
>>> arg_parser.parse_args(['--clean']) 
Namespace(clean=True, dirty=False)
>>> arg_parser.parse_args(['--dirty']) 
Namespace(clean=False, dirty=True)
>>> arg_parser.parse_args(['--dirty','--clean']) 
usage: PROG [-h] [-c | -d] PROG: error: argument -c/--clean: not allowed with argument -d/--dirty
```

Comment: I tried the same, but for arguments which are defined to get a value, but it didn't work:
group.add_argument("-v", "--verbose", type=str, nargs='?')
group.add_argument("-q", "--quiet", type=str, nargs='?')
Any idea why?